# VBA code to allow INDIRECT formula to drag over columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA but, I have a formula that is as follows:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Reference!$A$1&"PN GCS'!$N:$N"),'Area Summary PN'!$D101,INDIRECT("'"&Reference!$A$1&"PN GCS'!Q:Q"))
```

When this is dragged the last part "Q:Q" is hard coded and won't change columns.
Is there a way to get this to move columns as it is dragged?

The VBA code looks like this currently:

```
    Sheets("Area Summary PN").Select
    Range("JU101").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIF(INDIRECT(""'""&Reference!R1C1&""PN GCS'!$N:$N""),'Area Summary PN'!R[0]C4,INDIRECT(""'""&Reference!R1C1&""PN GCS'!Q:Q""))"         

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("JU101:JU111"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("JU101:JU111").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    
    Range("JU101").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I tried dragging and have not had any luck

Comment: Try `=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Reference!$A$1&"PN GCS'!N:N")`

Answer (score 0):

If you enter your formula in column `JU` and want to sum column `Q` the cell version should be:

```
    =SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Reference!$A$1&"PN GCS'!$N:$N"),'Area Summary PN'!$D101,
INDIRECT("'"&Reference!$A$1&"PN GCS'!C[-264]",))
```

The VBA version:

```
Range("JU101").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF(INDIRECT(""'""&Reference!R1C1&""PN GCS'!$N:$N""), 'Area Summary PN'!R[0]C4,INDIRECT(""'""&Reference!R1C1&""PN GCS'!C[-264]"",))"
```